# Cocossharp Simulate handle pull

Tags: xamarin, cocossharp

Is there any way to simulate a slot machine handle pull? I realize this is a 2D engine but I'm hoping someone knows a trick.

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo ? or provide more details.such as xamarin.android or forms, or you achieved a slot machine code like this link.https://github.com/atlanteh/react-native-slot-machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using Sprite animation with a sequence of images to simulate it.
Works like a charm!